# How to go back to a list of choices?

Tags: python

So I'm new to python. Just wanted to know, is it possible to use something like goto in c++.

I make a choice like this

```
print("1. choice")

print("2. choice")
print("3. choice")

choiceInput = input("Input your choice")

if choiceInput == 1:

    print("Bla bla bla")
```

After him choosing the 1 choice and getting what he chose, how do I make him get back to be able to choose from all of the 3 choices again?
Thanks, pretty new to python and just learning how to make a basic cmd app.

Comment: Why are you using `goto` in c++? Use a while loop conditioned on appropriate choice selection

Comment: @Chrispresso Its because I want it to go to a specific line of code, and not loop over the same thing over and over again. The same reason I want to use a goto in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop with one breaking condition.
The code can be as follows:

```
while True:
    print("1. choice")
    print("2. choice")
    print("3. choice")
    print("4. Exit.")

    choiceInput = int(input("Input your choice"))
    if choiceInput == 1:
       #code for 1.
    elif choiceInput == 2:
       #code for 2.
    elif choiceInput == 3:
       #code for 3.
    elif choiceInput == 4:
       break
```

Comment: Thanks, at the end of the choices, can I get the user to press or enter something to continue, so he can keep looking at the choice as long as he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop of some sort:

```
while True:
    print("1. choice")
    print("2. choice")
    print("3. choice")

    choiceInput = input("Input your choice")

    if choiceInput == 1:
        print("Bla bla bla")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, to execute the code again

```
print("1. choice")
print("2. choice")
print("3. choice")
print("4. STOP")

while True:
   choiceInput = int(input("Input your choice"))  # don't forget int conversion
    if choiceInput == 1:
        print("Bla bla bla")

    elif choiceInput == 4:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop to keep repeating

```py
while True:
    print("1. choice")
    print("2. choice")
    print("3. choice")

    choiceInput = input("Input your choice")

    if int(choiceInput) == 1: # Make sure to convert it to integer otherwise it will check between int and str
        print("Bla bla bla")
```

This will cause it to repeat after finishing. See the python wiki on [while loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

Answer (score 0):

```
def choice () :

    print("1. choice")
    print("2. choice")
    print("3. choice")

    choiceInput = input("Input your choice")
    return choiceInput


while True :
    choiceInput = choice()

    if choiceInput == "1":

        print("Bla bla bla")
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `input` returns a string, don't forget the `int conversion` first:

```py
choiceInput = int(input("Input your choice"))
```